# Are there any performance benefits of using else{} over always assigning a variable and only changing if condition met?

Tags: performance, optimization

Sorry for the poor title.

Take these cases:

**Case 1:**

```
a = true;
if (b)
{
    a = false
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
if (b)
{
    a = false
}
else
{
    a = true
}
```

Is there any performance difference in these cases?

Comment: Anything against case 3: `a = !b;` ?

Comment: @Jon - Nope. My case was actually more like `if (a || b) c=false; else c=true` but I'm sure there's some clever shorthand for that case too.

Comment: Well trivially: `c = !(a || b);` or alternatively `c = !a && !b;`

Comment: I think I'm getting it. If my observations are correct, `if (x << y && 12 >>> 1 || a) c = false` becomes case 3: `c = !(x << y && 12 >>> 1 || a)`. Thanks @Jon.

Comment: Yes - you're just assigning the inverse of the value of the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably try to specify the language/compiler/runtime.

In brief, no: in most cases optimising compiler will eliminate the difference.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose my question is directed toward C#, since that's where I came upon the case.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter which one is faster because these are micro-optimizations which don't affect running time at all (except for some situations) and because "premature optimization is the root of all evils". You should put all your efforts in optimizing the algorithm rather than these sharpness.
As @jalf said, a good compiler will compile them to the exact same code but if you're running your code on an ancient CPU the best one is the first one because it takes a brand less than the other.

Answer (score 0):

It generally depends on which compiler you use and which parameters get passed to it. It is definitely possible to optimise such conditions via dataflow analysis (i.e. [live variable analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis)), which most modern compilers are able to perform.